# Should Mono<T>.materialize return Flux<Signal<T>>?

Tags: java, project-reactor

According to its Javadoc on `Mono<T>.materialize()`:

> Transform the incoming onNext, onError and onComplete signals into Signal. Since the error is materialized as a Signal, the propagation will be stopped and onComplete will be emitted. Complete signal will first emit a Signal.complete() and then effectively complete the flux.

It means that the `Publisher` returned by `materialize` should at least emit 2 signal when no error is happening:

- `Signal.next`
- `Signal.complete`

However the return type of this method is `Mono<Signal<T>>` which only allows emitting single event. So I'm confused. The code should be

```
Flux<Signal<Integer>> mono = Mono.just(1).materialize();
StepVerifier.create(mono)
    .expectNext(Signal.next(1))
    .expectNext(Signal.complete())
    .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: I guess there's a  `;` missing on the first line as well as too much intendation on the following, right?

Comment: Thanks, I added that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Mono`, `materialize` only emits one `Signal`. Only 3 situations can occur on a Mono:

1. the mono is successful and **valued**: `Signal.next(value)` is emitted
2. the mono is successful but **empty**: `Signal.complete()` is emitted
3. the mono **errors**: `Signal.error(throwable)` is emitted

Comment: if that's the case, the Javadoc should be improved as it misleads me to assume that the return should be a `Flux`